# C# Media Player (VLC or WMP) Doesn't Play

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vlc, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm trying to build a simple media player. It has only Browse button, Play button and media player screen. I tried with Windows Media Player and VLC Media Player. In both codes below, `Button1` is for browsing the video. `Button2` is for playing. Browsing is working right but if I click Button2, nothing happens, and also I tried to see message if exists but it is not going to `catch`.

If I use Windows Media Player, I use this code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace videoplayerdeneme
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //textBox1.Text = opf.FileName;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = opf.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I want to use VLC Media Player, I use this code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace videoplayerdeneme
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //textBox1.Text = opf.FileName;
                axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(opf.FileName, opf.SafeFileName, null);
            }
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing in both cases? Please help me.

**EDIT**
I didn't add 64-bit VLC Media Player to Toolbox so I installed 32-bit version even my computer has 64-bit

Comment: Does the video you use for testing have audio? Do you hear the audio?

Comment: @NineBerry It has audio, but I don't hear audio

Comment: Please provide the full source code (including the Designer.cs code) and information on what file you use to test this. It works on my system. (Using Media Player ActiveX)